# How can I approach ruby background worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, backgroundworker, background-process

I am creating a stock market game on rails. Here I have a scenario where I want explore what are different approaches in running background jobs in ruby.

Scenario:
This application will have users. User will add other users as friends. Now my application will compare scores of these users and will send email to the user, if his/her friend is performing better than him/her to inspire him/her. Again app will be sending emails to user if he hasn't logged in in last 2 weeks. So mail triggers are away duration (> 2weeks) and user and their friends score comparison.

Points of discussion:

- I have briefly gone through Delayed_job, Resque. What would be the
  best library?
- If I want write a cron job in shell or other language will be more
  fast as in performance?
- Does above library uses separate processes for each queue or they use
  separate threads.

Please advice me on how should I approach this scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the whenever gem to control cron jobs is great:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

I would look at trying at least two from all available.

I would also focus a lot on getting a serious, realistic, volume of seed data ready for testing if not yet done.